# Check if a map is empty in Apache Velocity

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, velocity

In my java/spring app, I have a velocity template in which I create a map which will hold values also inserted in the template:

```
#set ($myMap = {})
```

What I want to do is have an if/else checking if the map is empty.  This doesn't seem to be working for me.  I've tried:

```
#if ($myMap.empty)
...
#if ($myMap.size == 0)
```

Neither of these work.  What is the correct way to check if a Map is empty in velocity.  I've tried searching the Documentation and SO, but I can't find an example.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`isEmpty` and `size` are methods, so they should be used like this:

```
#if ($myMap.isEmpty())
...
#if ($myMap.size() == 0)
```

Comment: The method should be `isEmpty()` - but once I used them as methods they worked.  I had expected that using them as properties would have called the JavaBeans method on them by default.

Comment: @JohnFarrelly You're right! I fixed the answer with the correct method name. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I added .getRows() before .isEmpty() to get it work :

```
#if($!rows.getRows().isEmpty() )
```